# Please I need someone to explain to me how to transfer polygon matic to a smart contract using solidity through a function

Tags: solidity, metamask, json-rpc, solidity-0.8.x

I keep getting this result anytime I try to call the "Subscribe" function from my contract.

I intend to make the function send some Mumbai test tokens to the contract and then give the user permission to stream as many songs as their subscription plan allows them.

I have tried all possible means but I don't seem to be getting a hang of it.

Below is the subscribe function.

```
 function subscribe(
    uint plan,
    address payable _user,
    // IERC20 _token,
    uint price
) public payable returns (bool success) {
    // require(_user == msg.sender);
    User storage user = users[_user];
    if (plan == 1) {
        require(token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) > 0);
        price = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), price));
        _user.transfer(price);
        user.playablePlaylists += 100;
        token.transferFrom(address(this), owner, (price / 11));
        user.isSubscribed = true;

        emit Subscribed(_user, price, plan);
        return true;
    }
    if (plan == 2) {
        require(token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) > 0);
        price = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), price));
        _user.transfer(price);
        user.playablePlaylists += 200;
        token.transferFrom(address(this), owner, price / 11);
        user.isSubscribed = true;

        emit Subscribed(_user, price, plan);
        return true;
    }
    if (plan == 3) {
        require(token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) > 0);
        price = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), price));
        _user.transfer(price);
        user.playablePlaylists += 300;
        token.transferFrom(address(this), owner, (price / 11));
        user.isSubscribed = true;

        emit Subscribed(_user, price, plan);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am also using the ERC20 token standard from openzeppellin, which signifies the "token" in the code.

[image: metamask error] This image is a screenshot of what my metamask looks like when I am about to send the transaction.

The error message I get at the end of the day is`RPC Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature. code: 4001 message: "MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature."`

Any explanation on how to fix this would really go a long way.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: I cannot just comment unfortunately. What keeps happening, what is the failure?
Force the transaction to land on chain and use tenderly.io to target the issue. Why do you only check the allowance is greater than zero?
Should you not check it is enough to cover "price"? Does the contract actually have the allowance to move the token?
Try manually setting the allowance for a test.

Comment: Hi TimilehinIsrael! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange. Please, user a more descriptive title, describe the exact problem, what are you expecting, and what are the results obtained. It is very hard to understand the problem from the contract alone.